# How can I make an automated filterede view based on content in a specific column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with multiple tasks grouped by headers. Depending on whether a task is marked (with a timeinterval) I want the task to appear in a filterede reduced outcome.

So differens students will have different work sheets when filled out.

Hov can I make this "filtering" automatically?

Please take a look at my [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15w_5nDNE3pZ1QBQcjb8rg32rbxDITiesJhZ2OqdliNQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Desierd output sheet `A1`

```
=FILTER('Actual sheet'!A:E; 'Actual sheet'!A:A<>"")
```

[image]